# Question posted through stack exchange API is not reflecting in stackoverflow

Tags: stackexchange-api

I tried to post a question in stack overflow with the API `/questions/add`. I used my generated access token and key of my registered application. The response did not throw any error but it is not reflected in stackoverflow either. The response neither gave the link to the question nor the question id.
[image: add question API]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Role of "preview" in "/questions/add"](https://stackapps.com/q/6420) by [Birkan Cilingir](https://stackapps.com/users/17233/birkan-cilingir)

> the preview parameter is used for development and testing purposes.
>
> If you set it to true, your request will only simulate whether it is a valid request or not and will not change anything on the site.

In your screenshot the `preview` property is true. So that only emulates the posting of the question. It looks like that succeeded without errors. Set the `preview` to false to actually post on the site.